# Feathersjs Revoking JWT's using Redis

Tags: redis, jwt, feathersjs

Feathersjs [Revoking JWT's](https://docs.feathersjs.com/cookbook/authentication/revoke-jwt.html) using Redis

Using the example provided not able to achieve the expected result, Token was not revoked it was re-authenticating, not able to figure out what was missing. Help is required, how to revoke JWT token.

Link - https://docs.feathersjs.com/cookbook/authentication/revoke-jwt.html has the redis example.

Answer (score 1):

Was successful in revoking JWT's using Redis.
Below is the code for the same

*redis.ts*

```
import * as  redis from 'redis';
import { Application } from './declarations';
import logger from './logger';

export default (app: Application) => {
  const { connection } = app.get('redis');

  const redisClient: redis.RedisClient = redis.createClient(connection);

  redisClient.on('connect', () => {
    logger.info('redis connected on %s:%d', connection.host, connection.port);
  });

  app.set('redisClient', redisClient);
};
```

*redis-authentication.ts*

```
import { promisify } from 'util';
import { AuthenticationService, AuthenticationResult, AuthenticationRequest } from '@feathersjs/authentication';
import { Application } from './declarations';
import { Params } from '@feathersjs/feathers';
import { NotAuthenticated } from '@feathersjs/errors';
import logger from './logger';

export class RedisAuthenticationService extends AuthenticationService {
  redis: any;
  constructor(app: Application, configKey?: string) {
    super(app, configKey);

    const redisClient = app.get('redisClient');

    // Promise wrapper for Redis client
    this.redis = {
      redisClient,
      get: promisify(redisClient.get.bind(redisClient)),
      set: promisify(redisClient.set.bind(redisClient)),
      exists: promisify(redisClient.exists.bind(redisClient)),
      expire: promisify(redisClient.expire.bind(redisClient))
    };
  }

  async revokeAccessToken(accessToken: any) {
    // First make sure the access token is valid
    const verified = await this.verifyAccessToken(accessToken);
    // Calculate the remaining valid time for the token (in seconds)
    const expiry = verified.exp - Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    // Add the revoked token to Redis and set expiration
    await this.redis.set(accessToken, 'true');
    await this.redis.expire(accessToken, expiry);
    return verified;
  }

  async verifyAccessToken(accessToken: any) {
    if (await this.redis.exists(accessToken)) {
      throw new NotAuthenticated('Token revoked');
    }
    return super.verifyAccessToken(accessToken);
  }

  async remove(id: string, params: Params) {
    const authResult = await super.remove(id, params);
    const { accessToken } = authResult;
    if (accessToken) {
      // If there is an access token, revoke it
      await this.revokeAccessToken(accessToken);
    }
    return authResult;
  }

}
```

*authentication.ts*

```
import { ServiceAddons } from '@feathersjs/feathers';
import { AuthenticationService, JWTStrategy } from '@feathersjs/authentication';
import { LocalStrategy } from '@feathersjs/authentication-local';
import { expressOauth } from '@feathersjs/authentication-oauth';
import { Application } from './declarations';
import { RedisAuthenticationService } from './redis-authentication';

declare module './declarations' {
  interface ServiceTypes {
    'authentication': AuthenticationService & ServiceAddons<any>;
  }
}

export default (app: Application) => {
  const authentication = new RedisAuthenticationService(app);

  authentication.register('jwt', new JWTStrategy());
  authentication.register('local', new LocalStrategy());

  app.use('/authentication', authentication);
  app.configure(expressOauth());
};
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer, just don't understand how we revoke it ?